# OpenACC: reduction operation on arrays

Tags: openacc

Is it possible to use the reduction operation "or" on the static array `flag[nx3_tot][nx2_tot][nx1_tot]` ?
here `FLAG_HLL=4` and `FLAG_MINMOD=1`. Without the reduction the results of this function running with or without OpenACC are different due to the lines:

```
flag[k][j][i+1] |= FLAG_MINMOD;
```

and I don't understand why: having the "or" operator `|` I would expect to have correct results even if different threads access the same memory address. But since this is the case I would like to use the reduction clause but I get the message:

**Reduction type not supported for this variable datatype - flag flag_shock.c**

**Sizeof dimensionless array  required flag_shock.c**

```
int flag[nx3_tot][nx2_tot][nx1_tot];
#pragma acc enter data create(flag[:nx3_tot][:nx2_tot][:nx1_tot])

#pragma acc parallel loop collapse(3) \
  present(d, grid, pt[:nx3_tot][:nx2_tot][:nx1_tot]) reduction(||:flag)
for (k = INCLUDE_KDIR; k < nx3_tot-INCLUDE_KDIR; k++){
for (j = INCLUDE_JDIR; j < nx2_tot-INCLUDE_JDIR; j++){
for (i = INCLUDE_IDIR; i < nx1_tot-INCLUDE_IDIR; i++){

double divv, gradp, pt_min;
double dpx1, pt_min1, dvx1;
double dpx2, pt_min2, dvx2;
double dpx3, pt_min3, dvx3;

pt_min = pt[k][j][i];
DIM_EXPAND(pt_min1 = MIN(pt[k][j][i+1], pt[k][j][i-1]); ,
           pt_min2 = MIN(pt[k][j+1][i], pt[k][j-1][i]);  ,
           pt_min3 = MIN(pt[k+1][j][i], pt[k-1][j][i]); )

DIM_EXPAND(pt_min = MIN(pt_min, pt_min1);  ,
           pt_min = MIN(pt_min, pt_min2);  ,
           pt_min = MIN(pt_min, pt_min3);)

DIM_EXPAND(dpx1 = fabs(pt[k][j][i+1] - pt[k][j][i-1]);  ,
           dpx2 = fabs(pt[k][j+1][i] - pt[k][j-1][i]);  ,
           dpx3 = fabs(pt[k+1][j][i] - pt[k-1][j][i]);)

gradp = DIM_EXPAND(dpx1, + dpx2, + dpx3);

if (gradp > EPS_PSHOCK_FLATTEN*pt_min) 
  {
  flag[k][j][i]   |= FLAG_HLL;
  flag[k][j][i]   |= FLAG_MINMOD;
  flag[k][j][i+1] |= FLAG_MINMOD;
  flag[k][j][i-1] |= FLAG_MINMOD;
  flag[k][j-1][i] |= FLAG_MINMOD;
  flag[k][j+1][i] |= FLAG_MINMOD;
  }

}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using reductions in this case.  Each thread would need it's own private copy of the array which would be quite a bit of memory given it's 3D, plus there's the overhead of performing the final reduction.

Instead, I'd recommend using atomic operations.  Since there will very few collisions on the elements, the overhead would be very low.

```
if (gradp > EPS_PSHOCK_FLATTEN*pt_min) 
  {
#pragma acc atomic update
  flag[k][j][i]   |= FLAG_HLL;
#pragma acc atomic update
  flag[k][j][i]   |= FLAG_MINMOD;
#pragma acc atomic update
  flag[k][j][i+1] |= FLAG_MINMOD;
.. etc ...
```

You don't mention which compiler or compiler version you're using.  If using NVHPC, array reduction support was added recently so if using an older compiler, this is why you'd be getting the message that this data type is not supported.

Comment: Thank you @mat. With #pragma acc atomic update it works fine. I would need now to use a different type of variable: d->flag[k][j][i] which is allocated dynamically instead of static allocated flag[k][j][i].

Comment: This doesn't work with #pragma acc atomic update: I get NVC++-S-0155-Invalid atomic expression and NVC++-S-0155-Invalid atomic region. While with #pragma acc atomic write I get call to cuStreamSynchronize returned error 716: Misaligned address

Comment: Or maybe the problem is that d->flag is an "uint16_t" not an "int"

Comment: Correct.  Under the hood the atomic maps to CUDA's atomicOr which only supports 32 or 64-bit values.  https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicor